# Automatic generation of const overload for member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am attempting to implement the semantics of the D language keyword `inout` in C++ (just for the fun of it).

Depending on context, it essentially says one of two things:

1. "The result of this function will have the same const-ness as one of its arguments."
2. "The result of this member function will have the same constness as the instance you call it on."

Useful when writing member functions like `begin` and `end`, among other cases.

I was able to create a valid implementation of the first case with relative ease (though the interface sure isn't pretty): http://ideone.com/wgaDJJ

The second, however, seems to be impossible by my best guess. You can only get this sort of "automatic const overload generation" when you use templates, but you can't template over the "this" argument, to my knowledge. In particular, you'll note that this code does *not* work/compile: http://ideone.com/W4fTa4

Was wondering:

1. Have I missed something? Is it possible to implement the second case without resorting to macros or code duplication?
2. Anyone know if there's a WG21 standards proposal on this subject? (not necessarily `inout`, just anything on topic)
3. What's the industry standard for dealing with this problem? (Here's a perhaps not-so-terrible option I was toying with: http://ideone.com/PW0vK4)

Comment: IMO the industry standard is to replicate the function, call the const one from the non-const one and just const_cast away problems. And it's just plain broken and in no way acceptable. A language mechanism is needed.

Comment: For method, you have to explicitly add `const` for `this` whereas for argument, the constness can be deduced in template.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answers**

1. No and no.
2. Barely related: more options for method overloading will come with Concepts Light.
3. Implement two method overloads, one `const` and one *non*-`const` (essentially, your last example).

**More details**

What you want to achieve in point 2

> The result of this member function will have the same constness as
>   the instance you call it on.

is a variation of the more general:

*Do something different in this method depending on the constness of the instance you call it on.*

The only way to do this in C++ is to have two method overloads that only differ in their constness. Since the type of `this` needs to be statically known, you cannot write a single method that works with two different types for `this`. Even with template methods, you have to explicitly write (or omit) the `const` modifier as there is no option to automatically generate a different template instantiation based just on the constness of `this`. You need to *"externalize"* `this` in some way if you want to be able to write a uniform template method. Essentially what you have done in your last example.

As for the industry standard, you need only look at the standard library itself. All the containers for example have method overloads for the `begin()`/`end()` methods that only differ by the constness, specifically to implement the functionality you want. (e.g.: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)

To my knowledge there is no particular proposal to implement a similar feature in the next standard. When it comes to overloading, one big new addition that might make it to C++17 is Concepts Light, which does add new ways to overload methods based on concepts. See some of the presentations/videos by Andrew Sutton on the topic (e.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZeTAnW5LL0, near the 50 minute mark, although you might want to watch the entire thing for background: )